# Question about calculating a series involving zeta functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

On [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254127/find-the-sum-of-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n3n13) page it had shown that the sum of $\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3}=10-\pi^2$. I'm curious about, what is the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3}$$
For some positive integer $k$.
According to partial fraction expansion, we can show that $$\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3}= 6\bigg(\frac1{nk^5}-\frac1{(n+k)k^5}\bigg)-3\bigg(\frac1{k^4n^2}+\frac1{k^4(n+k)^2}\bigg)+\frac1{k^3n^3}-\frac1{k^3(n+k)^3}$$

It is obvious to show that the first part and the last part are telescoping series, and for the last part, we can see that $$\frac1{k^3n^3}-\frac1{k^3(n+k)^3}=\frac1{k^3}\bigg(\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{(n+k)^3}\bigg)=\frac1{k^3}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac1{i^3}=\zeta(6)+\sum_{i<j}\frac1{i^3j^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3}$$
Which leads to the original question.
The particular values of the sum are

| $k$ | $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3}$$ |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $10-\pi^2$ |
| $2$ | $\frac {21}{32}-\frac1{16}\pi^2$ |
| $3$ | $\frac {809}{5832}-\frac1{81}\pi^2$ |

We can easily know that the sum is in the form of $a+b\pi^2$ and $b=\frac1{k^4}$. So what about the value of $a$?

---

Edit: Some notes on $\zeta(3)$:

By squaring $\zeta(3)$,
$$(\zeta(3))^2=\zeta(6)+\sum_{i\ne j}\frac1{i^3j^3}$$.

Note that $i$ and $j$ are both integers and we can assume that $i$ is strictly larger than $j$, or we could say that $i=n$, $j=n+k$ for some positive integer $k$. Hence
$$(\zeta(3))^2=\zeta(6)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3}$$

Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3} = a_k-\frac{\pi^2}{k^4}$.
Thus we can know
$$\begin{align}(\zeta(3))^2&=\zeta(6)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigg(a_k-\frac{\pi^2}{k^4}\bigg)\\&=\frac{\pi^6}{945}+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k-2\pi^2\zeta(4)\\&=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k-\frac{4\pi^6}{189}\end{align}$$

For $\sum_{k=1}^{10}a_k$, we can calculate that
$$\begin{align}(\zeta(3))^2&\approx 2\sum_{k=1}^{8}a_k-\frac{4\pi^6}{189}\\&\approx 1.42163941214...\end{align}$$

And $(\zeta(3))^2\approx1.44494079841...$

Comment: Nice question and problem ! $\to +1$

Comment: I would want to find this as this is part of the expansion of $(\zeta(3))^2$.

Comment: Why $(\zeta(3))^2$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've included this above.

Comment: "We can easily know that the sum is in the form of $a+b\pi^2$ and $b=\frac{1}{n^4}$" First, I think you mean $k$ instead of $n$, and, more importantly, there is good reason to doubt this behaviour because asymptotically we have $k^3 s(k) \simeq \zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^2}{2k}+O(\frac{\log(k)}{k^2})$ which is not compatible with your assumed behaviour.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze you are right since the particular values of this summation is very limited. Obviously one can calculate the values by hand but it doesn't imply for large value $k$. I would like to assume that the sum is in the form of $a+b\pi^2$ as it may be a way to calculate the sum from $k=1$ to $\infty$ by another intuition.

Comment: I wonder why there's still an open bounty. IMHO your question is completely solved. For your convenience I have just added a §3 to give an *explicit* derivation of my main result (1.1). What are you missing?

Comment: @xxxx036 I withdraw my comment of Sep 19 at 12:29 since the specific form you have provided is completely correct. I have shown this myself in (1.1) of my solution. It should be added moreover that your $a$ and $b$ are rational quantities. Nevertheless my wrong reasoning was interesting as it shows how one can be misled by asymptotic expansions which shows spurious irrationals ($\zeta(3)$ and $\log(k)$).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I am just attracting views from the community although your answer is mostly correct. If there are no other answers, the bounty will definitely go to you.

Comment: @xxxx036
 Many thanks for the bounty. In the meantime I have added the calculation of the general sum to my solution thus hopefully justifying the bounty ;-)

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze unfortunately there are no better answers. This shows that this is not the right path to find the closed form of Apery constant.

Comment: @xxxx036 Nicely expressed.. Unfortunately, you did not say what you were looking for beside an explicit formula for a function of a parameter $k$, and that's what you've got.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I believe your answer is the best answer for this question. It will be obvious to show if it is possible to find the closed form of Apery constant by observing the complexity of your answer.

Comment: @xxxx036 I think I have understood from your last comment what you were looking for: Apéry's constant. Now please notice (again) that in your sum $\zeta(3)$ cancels out, so you cannot use this type of sum to define Apéry's constant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

§1. Applying the general theory developed in §2 we find the following expression for the sum (see §3):

$$s(k) :=\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{n^3(n+k)^3} = -\frac{\pi^2}{k^4}+\frac{6}{k^5}H_{k}+\frac{3}{k^4}H_{k,2}+\frac{1}{k^3}H_{k,3}\tag{1.1} $$

where $H_{k,p} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{i^p}$ is the generalized harmonic number.

$(1)$ shows that your numbers $a_k$ defined more correctly with an index $k$ by the relation

$$s(k) = a_k-\frac{\pi^2}{k^4}\tag{1.2}$$

are given explicitly by

$$a_k = \frac{6}{k^5}H_{k}+\frac{3}{k^4}H_{k,2}+\frac{1}{k^3}H_{k,3}\tag{1.3}$$

The first few numbers are

$$a_k|_{k=01}^{k=10}=\{10, \frac{21}{32}, \frac{809}{5832}, \frac{2615}{55296},\frac{ 112831}{5400000}, \frac{168791}{15552000}, \frac{
17769701}{2823576000},\\
\frac{ 22201623}{5619712000},\frac{ 30715230979}{11666192832000}, \frac{
29416735711}{16003008000000}\}\tag{1.4}$$

Notice that these numbers have been given by Claude Leibovici earlier.

§2. For the derivation of even more general formulae for sums of the type

$$s(j,p,k,q) :=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{(n+j)^p (n+k)^q}\tag{2.1}$$

we start with the expression

$$\frac{1}{(n+j)(n+k)} = \frac{1}{k-j}(\frac{1}{n+j} -\frac{1}{n+k} )=\frac{1}{k-j}\left(\left(\frac{1}{n+j}-\frac{1}{n}\right) -\left(\frac{1}{n+k}+\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)$$

which after summing over $n$ gives

$$s(j,1,k,1) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{(n+j)(n+k)} \\
=\frac{1}{k-j}\sum_{n\ge 1} \left(\left(\frac{1}{n+j}-\frac{1}{n}\right) -\left(\frac{1}{n+k}+\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)=\frac{1}{k-j}(H_k - H_j)\tag{2.2}$$

Here we have used the representation of the harmonic number

$$H_k = \sum_{n\ge1}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+k})\tag{2.3}$$

Raising the (negative) powers $p$ and $q$ can be easily done by differentiating, viz.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial j}s(j,p,k,q) = - p\; s(j,p+1,k,q)\tag{2.4a}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}s(j,p,k,q) = - q\; s(j,p,k,q+1)\tag{2.4b}$$

and (from $(2.3))

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}H_k = \sum_{n\ge1} (\frac{1}{n+k})^2=\sum_{n\ge1} \left((\frac{1}{n+k})^2-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+ \sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2} = - H_{k,2}+\zeta(2)\tag{2.5}$$

The higher derivatives are given recursively by

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}H_{k,r} = r\left(\zeta(r+1) -H_{k,r+1}   \right)\tag{2.6}$$

and explicitly by

$$\frac{\partial^r}{\partial k^r}H_k =(-1)^{r+1} r!(\zeta(r+1)-H_{k,r+1}), r\ge 1\tag{2.7}$$

which follow from the definition

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}(\frac{1}{n^r} - \frac{1}{(n+k)^r} ) = H_{k,r}\tag{2.8}$$

Hence we find that the sums $s(i,p,k,q)$ can be expressed by $\zeta$-functions and (generalized) harmonic functions.

Wait! What happens when $j=k$ (a case we have tacidly excluded)? This case is just the simpler sum $s(j,p,k\to j,q) = s(j,p+q,j,0)$.

§3. Application to the specific case of the OP.

We can write

$$s(k) = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial j^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k^2}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{(n+j)(n+k)}|_{j \to 0}\\
=\frac{1}{4} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial j^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k^2}\frac{1}{k-j}(H_k - H_j)|_{j \to 0}\tag{3.1}$$

where in the last equality we have used $(2.2)$.

Now, using $(2.7)$, this can be easily converted into our main result $(1.1)$.

§4. Explicit expression for the general sum (2.1)

The shifted sum defined by $s_x(j,p,k,q) = s(j,p+1,k,q+1)$ is given by

$$\begin{align}s_x(j,p,k,q) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+j)^{p+1} (n+k)^{q+1}}\\=
+(-1)^q  \binom{p+q}{q} \frac{H_j}{(j-k)^{p+q+1}}\\
+(-1)^p  \binom{p+q}{q} \frac{H_k}{(k-j)^{p+q+1}}\\
+(-1)^{q} \sum _{m=1}^p \binom{p+q-m}{q} \frac{H_{j,m+1}-\zeta (m+1)}{(j-k)^{-m+p+q+1}}\\
+(-1)^{p} \sum _{n=1}^q \binom{p+q-n}{p}  \frac{H_{k,n+1}-\zeta (n+1)}{(k-j)^{-n+p+q+1}}\\
\end{align}\tag{4.1}$$

*Derivation*

Using

$$\begin{align}& \frac{1}{(j+n)^{p+1} (k+n)^{q+1}}\\
=&\frac{(-1)^{p+q}}{p! p!} \frac{\partial ^{(p+q)}}{\partial j^{p}\, \partial k^{q}}\left(\frac{1}{(j+n) (k+n)}\right)\end{align}\tag{4.2}$$

we have

$$\begin{align}sx(j,p,k,q) 
=&\frac{(-1)^{p+q}}{p! p!} \frac{\partial ^{(p+q)}}{\partial j^{p}\, \partial k^{q}}\left(\frac{H_{j}-H_{k}}{j-k}\right)\\
= &\frac{(-1)^{p+q}}{p! p!} D_{j}^{p} D_{k}^{q}\left(\frac{H_{j}-H_{k}}{j-k}\right)\\
\end{align}\tag{4.3}$$

We can write

$$\begin{align} &D_{j}^{p} D_{k}^{q}\left(\frac{H_{j}-H_{k}}{j-k}\right)
=D_{j}^{p} D_{k}^{q}\left(\frac{H_{j}}{j-k}\right)-D_{j}^{p} D_{k}^{q}\left(\frac{H_{k}}{j-k}\right)
\end{align}\tag{4.4}
$$

Carefully carrying out the derivatives with the first term

$$\begin{align} &D_{j}^{p} D_{k}^{q}\left(\frac{H_{j}}{j-k}\right)=D_{j}^{p}\left( H_{j} D_{k}^{q}\left(\frac{1}{j-k}\right)\right)\\
=&q! D_{j}^{p}\left( H_{j} \frac{1}{(j-k)^{q+1}}\right)\\
=&q!\sum _{m=0}^p \binom{p}{m} \left( D_{j}^{m} H_{j}\right) \left( D_{j}^{p-m}\frac{1}{(j-k)^{q+1}}\right)\\
=&q!\sum _{m=0}^p \binom{p}{m} \left( D_{j}^{m} H_{j}\right) \left(\frac{(-1)^{p-m} (-m+p+q)!}{q!}\frac{1}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1-m}} \right)\\
=&q!\left( H_{j}\right) \left(\frac{(-1)^{p} (p+q)!}{q!}\frac{1}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1}} \right)\\
+&q!\sum _{m=1}^p \binom{p}{m} \left( D_{j}^{m} H_{j}\right) \left(\frac{(-1)^{p-m} (-m+p+q)!}{q!}\frac{1}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1-m}} \right)\\
=& (-1)^{p} (p+q)!\frac{H_{j}}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1}}\\
+&\sum _{m=1}^p \binom{p}{m} \left( D_{j}^{m} H_{j}\right) \left(\frac{(-1)^{p-m} (-m+p+q)!}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1-m}} \right)\\
=& (-1)^{p} (p+q)!\frac{H_{j}}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1}}\\
+&\sum _{m=1}^p \binom{p}{m}(-1)^{m+1} m!\left(\zeta(m+1)-H_{j,m+1}\right) \left(\frac{(-1)^{p-m} (p+q-m)!}{ (j-k)^{p+q+1-m}} \right)
\end{align}
$$

The second term is transformed in a similar manner. Putting things togehther and simplifying gives $(4.1)$ as requested.

§5. Discussion

The general sum is composed of a transcendental part and a rational part.

Notice that this structure might be conceiled if polygamma functions are used.

The transcendental part is a linear combination of $\zeta$-functions with rational coefficients, the rational part is a similar linear combination of (generalized) harmonic numbers.

This structure is exhibited already in $(1.1)$.

The transcendental part TP of the sum

$$s_x(j,p,k,q)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+j)^{p+1} (n+k)^{q+1}}$$

for some values of $p$ and $q$ in the format $\{\{p,q\},TP(s_x)\}$ are (here $d=j-k$)

For $q=p$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \{\{0,0\},0\} \\
 \left\{\{1,1\},\frac{2 \zeta(2)}{d^2}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{2,2\},-\frac{6 \zeta(2)}{d^4}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{3,3\},\frac{20 \zeta(2)}{d^6}+\frac{2 \zeta(4)}{d^4}\right\} \\
\end{array}
$$

As mentioned before, for $p=q$ only even $\zeta$-functions appear.

For $q=p+1$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \left\{\{0,1\},\frac{\zeta(2)}{d}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{1,2\},\frac{\zeta(3)}{d^2}-\frac{3 \zeta(2)}{d^3}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{2,3\},\frac{10 \zeta(2)}{d^5}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{d^3}-\frac{2 \zeta(3)}{d^4}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{3,4\},-\frac{35 \zeta(2)}{d^7}+\frac{5 \zeta(3)}{d^6}+\frac{\zeta(5)}{d^4}-\frac{5 \zeta(4)}{d^5}\right\} \\
\end{array}
$$

For $q=p+2$

$$\begin{array}{c}
 \left\{\{0,2\},\frac{\zeta(3)}{d}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{d^2}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{1,3\},\frac{4 \zeta(2)}{d^4}-\frac{2 \zeta(3)}{d^3}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{d^2}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{2,4\},-\frac{15 \zeta(2)}{d^6}+\frac{5 \zeta(3)}{d^5}-\frac{3 \zeta(4)}{d^4}+\frac{\zeta(5)}{d^3}\right\} \\
 \left\{\{3,5\},\frac{56 \zeta(2)}{d^8}-\frac{14 \zeta(3)}{d^7}+\frac{11 \zeta(4)}{d^6}-\frac{4 \zeta(5)}{d^5}+\frac{\zeta(6)}{d^4}\right\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Very interesting generalization.

Comment: Mathematica gives the fully simplified result $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3(n+k)^3}=\frac{1}{2 k^5}\left(k^2 (\psi ^{(2)}(k+1)+2 \zeta (3))-\pi ^2 k-6 k \psi ^{(1)}(k+1)+12 \psi ^{(0)}(k+1)+12 \gamma\right)$ which seems inconsistent with formula (1) above but consistent with the answer posted by @ClaudeLeibovici.

Comment: @Steven Clark Just for clarity, pease explain what you mean by "(your expression) seems inconstent with formula (1)" (now (1.1))

Comment: It seems the $-\frac{\pi^4}{k^4}$ term in formula (1.1) should really be $-\frac{\pi ^2}{k^4}$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing this typo out. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

Using partial summation and asymptotics, we have $$a_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3(n+k)^3}+\frac {\pi^2}{k^4}$$
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2k ^5}\Big[k^2 (\psi ^{(2)}(k+1)+2 \zeta (3))+\pi ^2 k-6 k \psi ^{(1)}(k+1)+12 \psi^{(0)}(k+1)+12 \gamma \Big]$$ which generate the sequence
$$\left\{10,\frac{21}{32},\frac{809}{5832},\frac{2615}{55296},\frac{112831}{54000
   00},\frac{168791}{15552000},\frac{17769701}{2823576000},\frac{22201623}{5619
   712000},\dots\right\}$$

I did not find anything in $OEIS$ but the asymptotics is
$$a_k=\frac{\zeta (3)}{k^3}+\frac{\pi ^2}{2 k^4}+\frac{12 \log (k)+12 \gamma
   -7}{2k^5}+\frac 5 {k^6}-\frac 5 {4k^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^9}\right)$$ which is not bad even for small values of $k$. Using this truncated series, we have
$$a_1=\zeta (3)+\frac{1}{4}+6 \gamma +\frac{\pi ^2}{2}=9.85015\cdots$$
$$a_2=\frac{64 \zeta (3)-21+96 \gamma +16 \pi ^2+96 \log (2)}{512} =0.65586\cdots$$

Comment: Good job, and numerically valid, but notice that there is no $\zeta(3)$ in the exact result (cf. my solution). All terms except $\frac{\pi^2}{k^4}$ are rational quantities.

Comment: Notice that the non trivial coefficients {6,3,1} of the harmonic numbers in my formula (1.1) can be found in OEIS A092392, in fact they are just C(2n-k,n) with n=2, k=0..2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a smooth and **Elementary** way of solving the problem .

> I'll use the fact that $$\frac{1}{a.b}=\frac{1}{(b-a)}{\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)}$$

So , $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n(n+k)}\right)^3=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+k)}\right)^3$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{k^3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\underbrace{\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{(n+k)^3}}_{H^{(3)}_{k}}-\frac{3}{n(n+k)}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+k)}\right)\tag{*}$$

> Now we need to compute this sum .$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n(n+k)}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+k)}\right)\Rightarrow3\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{n^2(n+k)^2}}\tag{1}$$
> Second sum which we have to compute is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n(n+k)}\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+k)}\right)^2$$ $$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}-\frac{2}{n(n+k)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{k^2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}+\color{red}{\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2}}_{\zeta(2)}}-H_{k}^{(2)}-\color{green}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+k)}}\right)\tag{2}$$ The third sum which we need to compute is $$\Rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+k)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+k)}\right)=\frac{1}{k}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+k)}\right)$$
> $$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}=\color{green}{\frac{H_k^{(1)}}{k}}\tag{3}$$

Now finally assembling all the sums we get , $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n(n+k)}\right)^2=\frac{1}{k^2}\left(2\zeta(2)-H_k^{(2)}-\frac{2H_k^{(1)}}{k}\right)\tag{4}$$
Using the value of sum from equation $(4)$ to equation $(*)$ , we'll get $$\frac{1}{k^3}\left(H_k^{(3)}-\frac{3}{k}\left(2\zeta(2)-H_k^{(2)}-\frac{2H_k^{(1)}}{k}\right)\right)$$ $$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{k^3}\left(H_k^{(3)}-\frac{6\zeta(2)}{k}+\frac{3H_k^{(2)}}{k}+\frac{6H_k^{(1)}}{k^2}\right)$$ $$\Rightarrow\color{red}{\underbrace{\frac{H_k^{(3)}}{k^3}+\frac{3H_k^{(2)}}{k^4}+\frac{6H_k^{(1)}}{k^5}}_{a}}-\frac{\pi^2}{k^4}$$