# Finding similar series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I recently discovered this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^4}=\frac{2^2}{1^4}+\frac{3^2}{2^4}+\frac{4^2}{3^4}+...=\zeta(2)+2\zeta(3)+\zeta(4)$$
It can also be written as
$$\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{3}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\frac{5}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{3}{3^4}+\frac{5}{3^4}+\frac{7}{3^4}+...$$
This also applies to higher degrees, for example:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^6}=\zeta(6)+2\zeta(5)+\zeta(4)$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^4}{n^6}=\zeta(6)+4\zeta(5)+6\zeta(4)+4\zeta(3)+\zeta(2)$$
I'm not very clear if any one of these would have something surprising.
I would like to know if there are any similar series throughout the currently published documents.

Comment: What do you mean by similar series ?

Comment: @Tryhard since the zeta function only involves the denominator, I would like to find some 'harmonic' series that involves both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Don't you think this kind of formulas is rather "trivial" (although I dislike this adjective...): $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$ ? ...

Comment: @Jean Marie the thing I am targeting is to eliminate the odd powers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, @xxxx036 I have seen some of [your questions on zeta functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254358/question-about-calculating-a-series-involving-zeta-functions) they were so interesting and tough that I was finding difficulties in understanding but this disappointed me.

$$\sum_{n \ge1}\frac{(n+1)^p}{n^q} = \sum_{n\ge1}\frac {\sum_{k =0}^pn^k}{n^q} = \sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{k =1}^p\binom pkn^{k - q} = \sum_{k =1}^p\binom pk\sum_{n\ge1}n^{k - q} =  \sum_{k =1}^p\binom pk\zeta(q-k)$$
Here, $q-p\ge2$

$\zeta(n) = \sum_{k\ge1}H_k^n$